# Does online video players download the video in background?

Tags: video, html5-video, video-processing

I have this question that when you watch an online video, does your video player actually download the video in the background ? And if it does download the video in the background then can you please explain what and why is the difference in the file size compared to if i practically download that video.

Answer (score 0):

Then term “download” just means copying bytes from the server to the client. So, yes a video player does download the video, or else it couldn’t play it. The size is determined before the video is played. If you download the same video twice (once via a player, and one via another method), it’s the exact same file, and therefore the exact same file size.